# Knockout JS - foreach: data-bind not get refreshed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

SPEC : Building a customer support application.

First time, when a user send a message able to save to DB and show in the view without any issues. And from my end, if i send I am able to push the data to the UI as well DB and the user is able to get the message.

But the issue is when the user send back response again, its not showing up refreshing the UI.

Below is my knockout code,

```
var csendpoints = {
"Active": "/cs/oc/",
"ActiveClientData": "/cs/gnm/",
"Archive": "/cw/archive/",
"Dequeue": function (id) { return "/cw/dequeue/" + id; },
"GetQueue": "/cs/q/",
"GetArchive": "/cs/h/",
"GetActive": "/cs/active/",
"RecentlyQueued": "/cs/rq/",
"Send": "/cs/send",
"SitRep": "/cw/sitrep",
};
var customerSupportViewModel;

 function PagedViewModels(model) {
var self = this;
self.Items = ko.observableArray(model.Items || []);
self.MetaData = ko.observable(model.MetaData || "");
}

function PagedListMetaDataViewModel(model) {
var self = this;
self.FirstItemOnPage = ko.observable(model.FirstItemOnPage || "");
self.HasNextPage = ko.observable(model.HasNextPage || "");
self.HasPreviousPage = ko.observable(model.HasPreviousPage || "");
self.IsFirstPage = ko.observable(model.IsFirstPage || "");
self.IsLastPage = ko.observable(model.IsLastPage || "");
self.LastItemOnPage = ko.observable(model.LastItemOnPage || "");
self.PageCount = ko.observable(model.PageCount || "");
self.PageNumber = ko.observable(model.PageNumber || "");
self.PageSize = ko.observable(model.PageSize || "");
self.TotalItemCount = ko.observable(model.TotalItemCount || "");
}

function ConversationMessageViewModels(model) {
var self = this;
self.ClientId = ko.observable(model.ClientId || "");
self.ClientName = ko.observable(model.ClientName || "");
self.ClientSex = ko.observable(model.ClientSex || "");
self.ClientLanguage = ko.observable(model.ClientLanguage || "");
self.ClientProvince = ko.observable(model.ClientProvince || "");
self.ClientCountry = ko.observable(model.ClientCountry || "");
self.ClientCity = ko.observable(model.ClientCity || "");
self.ClientProfileImage = ko.observable(model.ClientProfileImage || "");
self.ClientContent = ko.observable(model.ClientContent || "");
self.Content = ko.observable(model.Content || "");
self.ConversationMessageId = ko.observable(model.ConversationMessageId ||     "");
self.dummy = ko.observable();
self.Sender = ko.observable(model.Sender || "");
self.SentOn = ko.observable(model.SentOn || "");
self.SentOnUniversalSortable = ko.observable(model.SentOnUniversalSortable || "");
self.SentTimeFromNow = ko.computed(function () {
    self.dummy();
    return moment.utc(self.SentOnUniversalSortable()).fromNow();
});


function updateTimeFromNow() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        self.dummy.notifySubscribers();
        updateTimeFromNow();
    },
        60 * 1000);
}

updateTimeFromNow();
}

function ConversationViewModels(model) {
var self = this;
self.ClientId = ko.observable(model.ClientId || "");
self.ClientName = ko.observable(model.ClientName || "");
self.ClientProfileImage = ko.observable(model.ClientProfileImage || "");
self.ClientSex = ko.observable(model.ClientSex || "");
self.ClientLanguage = ko.observable(model.ClientLanguage || "");
self.ClientProvince = ko.observable(model.ClientProvince || "");
self.ClientCountry = ko.observable(model.ClientCountry || "");
self.ClientCity = ko.observable(model.ClientCity || "");
self.ClientNameInitial = ko.observable(model.ClientName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
self.ClientContent = ko.observable(model.ClientContent || "");
self.ConversationId = ko.observable(model.ConversationId || "");
self.CreatedOn = ko.observable(model.CreatedOn || "");
self.MessagePreview = ko.observable(model.MessagePreview || "");
self.Messages = ko.observableArray([]);
self.ProfileImageUrl = ko.observable(model.ProfileImageUrl || "");
self.Sender = ko.observable(model.Sender || "");
self.SupportName = ko.observable(customerSupportViewModel.CustomerSupportName());
self.TextBoxContent = ko.observable("");
self.TextBoxEnabled = ko.observable(true);

self.MakeActive = function () {
    customerSupportViewModel.WaitingList.remove(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.ArchivedConversations.remove(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.ActiveConversation(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.CurrentConversations.push(self);
    $.ajax(csendpoints.Active + self.ConversationId(),
    {
        success: console.log("Debug: Now Active")
    });
};

self.MakeRemoveMultiActive = function () {
    customerSupportViewModel.WaitingList.remove(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.ArchivedConversations.remove(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.ActiveConversation(self);
    //customerSupportViewModel.CurrentConversations.push(self);
    //customerSupportViewModel.CurrentConversations.remove(self);
    $.ajax(csendpoints.Active + self.ConversationId(),
    {
        success: console.log("Debug: Now Active")
    });
    $("#chat-wrap").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
    $("#chat-wrap").height($(window).height() - 314);
    $("#chat-wrap")
           .mCustomScrollbar({
               axis: "y",
               scrollEasing: "linear",
               scrollButtons: { enable: true },
               theme: "dark-thick",
               scrollbarPosition: "inside",
               mouseWheelPixels: 400
           });
    initMap()
};
self.Archive = function () {
    customerSupportViewModel.ArchivedConversations.push(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.ActiveConversation('');
    customerSupportViewModel.CurrentConversations.remove(self);
    customerSupportViewModel.WaitingList.remove(self);

    customerSupportViewModel.RefreshWaiting();
    customerSupportViewModel.RefreshActive();
    customerSupportViewModel.RefreshArchive();
    $.ajax(csendpoints.Archive + self.ConversationId(),
    {
        success: console.log("Debug: Now Archived")
    });
};
self.SendMessage = function (data) {
    self.TextBoxEnabled(false);
    var msj = {
        "SentOn": moment.utc().format(),
        "SentOnUniversalSortable": moment().format(),
        "Sender": 1,
        "SenderName": customerSupportViewModel.CustomerSupportName(),
        "Content": self.TextBoxContent(),
        "ClientId": self.ClientId(),
        "ClientName": self.ClientName()
    };

    self.Messages.push(new ConversationMessageViewModels(msj));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: csendpoints.Send,
        data: $(data).serialize(),
        success: function () { },
        complete: function () {
            self.TextBoxContent("");
            self.TextBoxEnabled(true);
        }
    });
};


_.each(model.Messages, function (item) {
    self.Messages.push(new ConversationMessageViewModels(item));
});
var sortedMessages = _.sortBy(self.Messages(),
    function (iteratedItem) { return iteratedItem.SentOnUniversalSortable(); });
self.Messages(sortedMessages);

}


function CustomerSupportViewModel(model) {
var self = this;
customerSupportViewModel = self;

function getWaitingList(page) {
    $.ajax(csendpoints.GetQueue + page,
    {
        success: function (data) {
            self.WaitingList.removeAll();

            _.each(data.Items, function (item) { self.WaitingList.push(new ConversationViewModels(item)); });

            self.WaitingListPaging(data.MetaData);
        }
    });
}

function getActiveList(page) {
    $.ajax(csendpoints.GetActive + page,
    {
        success: function (data) {
            self.CurrentConversations.removeAll();

            _.each(data.Items, function (item) { self.CurrentConversations.push(new ConversationViewModels(item)); });

            self.CurrentConversationsPaging(data.MetaData);
        }
    });
}

function getArchiveList(page) {
    $.ajax(csendpoints.GetArchive + page,
    {
        success: function (data) {
            self.ArchivedConversations.removeAll();

            _.each(data.Items, function (item) {
                self.ArchivedConversations.push(new ConversationViewModels(item));
            });

            self.ArchivedConversations(data.MetaData);
        }
    });
}


// Conversations in Queue(i.e. waiting), Current(i.e. active) and Archive (i.e. history)
self.WaitingList = ko.observableArray([]);
self.ArchivedConversations = ko.observableArray([]);
self.CurrentConversations = ko.observableArray([]);

// Paging models
self.WaitingListPaging = ko.observable(model.ConversationsInQueue.MetaData);
self.ArchiveListPaging = ko.observable(model.ArchivedConversations.MetaData);
self.CurrentConversationsPaging = ko.observable(model.CurrentConversations.MetaData);

// The conversation currently active.
self.ActiveConversation = ko.observable();
//setInterval(self.ActiveConversation, 500);
// The name of the WeChatAccount serving the client
self.CustomerSupportName = ko.observable(model.CustomerSupportName);


self.RefreshWaiting = function () {
    var page = self.WaitingListPaging().PageNumber;
    getWaitingList(page);
};
self.RefreshActive = function () {
    var page = self.CurrentConversationsPaging().PageNumber;
    getActiveList(page);
    //getWaitingList(page);
};
self.RefreshArchive = function () {
    var page = self.ArchiveListPaging().PageNumber;
    //getArchiveList(page);
    getWaitingList(page);
};
//self.RefreshChatActive = function () {
//    getActiveList()
//};

// ###### PAGING for Waiting / Queue ######
// Forward paging for the queue / waiting list
self.NextPageWaitingList = function () {
    if (self.WaitingListPaging().IsLastPage) return;
    var page = self.WaitingListPaging().PageNumber + 1;
    getWaitingList(page);
};
self.PreviousPageWaitingList = function (data, e) {
    //console.log($(data))
    //console.log((e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement)

    if (self.WaitingListPaging().IsFirstPage) return;

    var page = self.WaitingListPaging().PageNumber - 1;
    getWaitingList(page);
};

//  ###### PAGING for Active / Current conversations ######
self.NextPageActiveList = function () {
    if (self.CurrentConversations().IsLastPage) return;
    var page = self.CurrentConversations().PageNumber + 1;
    getActiveList(page);
};
self.PreviousPageActiveList = function () {
    if (self.CurrentConversations().IsFirstPage) return;
    var page = self.CurrentConversations().PageNumber - 1;
    getActiveList(page);
};

//  ###### PAGING for History / Archived conversations ######
self.NextPageArchiveList = function () {
    if (self.ArchivedConversations().IsLastPage) return;
    var page = self.ArchivedConversations().PageNumber + 1;
    getArchiveList(page);
};
self.PreviousPageArchiveList = function (data, e) {
    if (self.ArchivedConversations().IsFirstPage) return;
    var page = self.ArchivedConversations().PageNumber - 1;
    getArchiveList(page);
};


_.each(model.ConversationsInQueue.Items,
    function (item) { self.WaitingList.push(new ConversationViewModels(item)); });
_.each(model.CurrentConversations.Items,
    function (item) { self.CurrentConversations.push(new ConversationViewModels(item)); });
_.each(model.ArchivedConversations.Items,
    function (item) { self.ArchivedConversations.push(new ConversationViewModels(item)); });


function getNewQueue(page) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax(csendpoints.GetQueue + page,
        {
            success: function (data, odata) { getNewQueue(); }
        });
    },
        15 * 1000);
}
}

var customerSupportViewModel = new CustomerSupportViewModel(jsonViewModel);
window.setInterval(customerSupportViewModel.RefreshWaiting, 1000);
window.setInterval(customerSupportViewModel.RefreshActive, 200);
window.setInterval(customerSupportViewModel.Messages, 200);

ko.applyBindings(customerSupportViewModel);

var conversationMessageViewModels = new       ConversationMessageViewModels(jsonViewModel);
```

Here MakeRemoveMultiActive is used as a click function, and in the view, it load the data what user sent as well the response sent from my end. Note, this happens only on click event.

I want to update the UI after the click event so the view is open with the data and autoupdates.

Request experts to shed some light.

Comment: Can you trim out the code that isn't central to demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You declare `customerSupportViewModel` twice.

Comment: @RoyJ not sure why i am not able to edit. If you check `self.MakeRemoveMultiActive ` that the one called on the click. Which will load a another div with the currently clicked data.